# php bin/magento setup:upgrade SHOW ERROR : Connection "default" is not defined

Tags: magento2, cli, setup-upgrade, magento2.3.6

Setup upgrade command not running.
The issue is given below in screenshot.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can check do these:

```
- Information Provided in the env is correct
- Elastic Search is working properly or not 
- Check the mode
- Check the core_config_table
```